# Angular5 manipulation Html of other component without having child/parent relation

Tags: html, angular, communication

For my application I have to communicate with 2 components but these components don`t have a parent child relation.

I use a service to set up this comminication. When I click on the button on of component1 I trigger a function in compenent2. Normaly this function makes a change in the html of component2 when i trigger it from component2. But when I trigger it from component1 nothing happens. Is there a way to reload/update the HTML when component1 triggers the function in component2?

THx a lot!

Comment: Please post code here so we can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be issue with your service communication, as far as I have used it, worked fine for me.
Make sure you subscribe to the service in constructor of component in which you want to receive any value.
In your case,

```
 import { Subject,Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
 code for service :
   public methodForRender = new Subject<any>();
   renderMe = this.methodForRender.asObservable();
   callMethodToRender(value) {
    this.methodForRender.next(value);
   }

 code for component 1 :  which is triggering function!

   constructor(private callingBridge: SharedService) {}
   this.callingBridge.callMethodToRender(this.value);

 code for component 2 :  which should be subscribed to service 

    constructor(private callingBridge: SharedService) {}
    this.callingBridge.renderMe.subscribe(
     (value) => {
        // do your stuff // call your function here to render html
       }
    );
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Could you just explain what renderMe is in the service?
is it just a variable I don`t get it! ( renderMe = this.methodForRender.asObservable(); )

Comment: renderMe is a variable which stores the value of object methodForRender, it hides the identity of source, or I should say to hide implementation of rx subject by using asObservable instance..
this link can help you more to understand : https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3048-converting-a-subject-to-an-observable-using-rxjs-in-angular-2.htm