# Pass data to other page/component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I have my user input as below in my html file:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="btsIp"><strong>BTS IP:</strong></label> <input ngModel type="text"
    name="btsIp" class="form-control" id="btsIp" (blur)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="btsIp">
</div>
```

In my `component.ts` i am using it as
`btsIp: any` and passing it in my request

```js
let Data = {
  "btsIp": this.btsIp
}
```

which is working fine. But i want to pass this `btsIp` value to another `page/Component` where i need to call a request again where i need to pass the same `btsIp` value.

Could you all please help?

Comment: Using shared service https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Refer to this : [Communication between two components in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755984/angular5-manipulation-html-of-other-component-without-having-child-parent-relati/)

Answer (score 2):

Passing data to the other page/component, it depends on whether it's the parent component, a sibling component, or a completely unrelated component in a different route.

- Parent component: you can trigger a parent's component function by hooking on the `@Output` of the child component. Or you can access child component's properties via `@ViewChild` declaration. Read more: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
- Sibling component: first transfer to the parent component as describe above, then pass the data from parent to child component via child's `@Input`.
- A completely different page in a different route: you can pass the data via route params. Read more: https://angular.io/guide/router

Other approach: if you can afford using NgRx (state management inspired by Redux powered by RxJs for Angular), everything will be much easier once you mastered it, but that's a huge other topic that cannot be included in this answer box. More at https://github.com/ngrx/platform

Answer (score -1):

Create a new ts File, inject that in to your module, use get and set

```
  get IP (){
    return this.btsIp;
  }

  set IP (btsIp){
    this.btsIp= btsIp;
  }
```

Hope it would help

Comment: This might work but it's not the Angular way. Btw, this approach is so weird. How about there're multiple pair of parents and children, this won't work.